A Limited Sense of Path Integral Respecting Classical EOM
In Weinberg QFT V1, we got the general path integral of time-ordered operators product, equation (9.1.38),
$$\langle{q',t'|\text{T}\left\{\mathcal{O}_A\left(P(t_A),Q(t_A)\right)\mathcal{O}_B\left(P(t_B),Q(t_B)...\right)\right\}\rangle}=$$
$$\int{\prod_{\tau,a}dq_{a}(\tau)}\prod_{\tau,b}\frac{dp_{b}(\tau)}{2\pi}\mathcal{O}_{A}\left(p(t_A),q(t_A)\right)\mathcal{O}_B\left(p(t_B),q(t_B)\right)...$$
$$\times\exp\left[i\int_{t}^{t'}d\tau\,\left\{\sum_{a}\dot{q}_a(\tau)p_{a}(\tau)-H(q(\tau),p(\tau))\right\}\right]\tag{9.1.38}$$
$a$ and $b$ are particles' indices.
He says that $q_a(\tau)$ and $p_a{\tau}$ appearing in the equation are merely variables of integration, and are not constrained to obey the classical Hamiltonian eom. (see 9.1.39 and 9.1.40), take 9.1.39 for instance,
$$\dot{q}_{a}(\tau)-\frac{\partial H (q,p)}{\partial p_a(\tau)} = 0\tag{9.1.39}$$
However, if we take $\mathcal{O}_{A}\left(p(t_A),q(t_A)\right)$ to be LHS of above equation, we would have,
$$\mathcal{O}_{A}\left(p(t_A),q(t_A)\right)\exp(iI[q,p]) = -i\frac{\delta}{\delta p_a(t_A)}\exp(iI[q,p])\tag{p.383} $$
Where $I$ is the exponent of (9.1.38).
Weinberg then claims on p. 383 that

As long as $t_A$ doesn't approach $t$ or $t'$ (which $q_a(t)$ and $q_a(t')$ are fixed), then the integrations 9.1.38 over $q_a(t_A)$ and $p_a(t_A)$ are unconstrainted, which I can understand.

There is reasonable assumptions that the integrations are convergent.



and 2. imply the integral with such variational derivatives must vanish.



I don't understand how 3. is valid at all since I know that $p_a(\tau)$ and $q_a(\tau)$ don't obey classical eom, so the variational derivative wouldn't trivially vanish at all, how come Weinberg can use 1. and 2. to imply 3.?

Weinberg's claim (3.) essentially boils down to the statement that the path integral of a functional derivative at some instant $t_A$ vanishes as long as $t_A$ is away from the initial/final time and times of other operator insertions, cf. e.g. this Phys.SE post.
